# Find the supremum and infimum of the set $S = \{ \sqrt {n^2 + 1} - n: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Find the supremum and infimum of the set $S = \{ \sqrt {n^2 + 1} - n: n \in 
 \mathbb{N} \}.$
I know that the supremum is $\sqrt{2} - 1$ but what about the infimum is it $0$?

Could anyone tell me if I am right or wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The perennial classic
$$ \sqrt{n^2+1}-n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}+n} $$
should convince you that you're correct: it's clear that this is a decreasing function of $n$, and smaller than $1/(2n)$, which also tends to zero.

Answer (score 2):

More generally,
if 
$f(n) \to \infty$
and
$\dfrac{g(n)}{f(n)}
\to 0$,
then

$\begin{array}\\
\sqrt{f^2(n)+g(n)}-f(n)
&=(\sqrt{f^2(n)+g(n)}-f(n))\dfrac{\sqrt{f^2(n)+g(n)}+f(n)}{\sqrt{f^2(n)+g(n)}+f(n)}\\
&=\dfrac{(f^2(n)+g(n))-f^2(n)}{\sqrt{f^2(n)+g(n)}+f(n)}\\
&=\dfrac{g(n)}{\sqrt{f^2(n)+g(n)}+f(n)}\\
&\to 0\\
\end{array}
$

Your case is
$f(n) = n$ and
$g(n) = 1$.

Note that if
$\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{g(n)}{f(n)}= L
$,
then
$\sqrt{f^2(n)+g(n)}-f(n)
\to \frac12 L
$.

For example,
if $f(n) = g(n) = n$,
then
$\sqrt{n^2+n}-n
\to \frac12 
$.